# Plotting Log-normal scale in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scale, normal-distribution

I've got these two lists which are x,y points to be plotted:

```
microns = [38,  45,  53,  63,  75,  90, 106, 125, 150, 180]
cumulative_dist = [25.037, 32.577, 38.34, 43.427, 51.57,56.99, 62.41,69.537,74.85, 81.927]
```

The thing is I need to plot them following the scale showed in the image below ([more info here](https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/25ba6e5f/files/uploaded/ASL%20log%20table_3KIpAwPPS76DImash44j.pdf)), which is a log-normal plot.

How can I get this scale using matplotlib?

I guess I'll need to use [matplotlib.scale.FuncScale](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.FuncScale), but I'm not quite sure how to get there.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you want to use `probplot`? https://matplotlib.org/mpl-probscale/tutorial/closer_look_at_viz.html#probability-plots

Comment: It looks like what I want. I'll have a look at it. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5851928/davidg)'s insightful comment I've read [this](https://matplotlib.org/mpl-probscale/tutorial/closer_look_at_viz.html#probability-plots) page and managed to plot the Figure the way I wanted.

[image]

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, AutoLocator
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pd
import probscale
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
microns = [38,  45,  53,  63,  75,  90, 106, 125, 150, 180]
cumulative_dist = [25.037, 32.577, 38.34, 43.427, 51.57,56.99, 62.41,69.537,74.85, 81.927]
probscale.probplot(pd.Series(microns, index=cumulative_dist), ax=ax, plottype='prob', probax='y', datascale='log',
                   problabel='Cumulative Distribution (%)',datalabel='Particle Size (μm)',
                   scatter_kws=dict(marker='.', linestyle='none', markersize=15))
ax.set_xlim(left=28, right=210)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=1, top=99)
ax.set_title('Log Normal Plot')
ax.grid(True, axis='both', which='major')
formatter = ScalarFormatter()
formatter.set_scientific(False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(AutoLocator())
ax.set_xticks([])  # for major ticks
ax.set_xticks([], minor=True)  # for minor ticks
ax.set_xticks(microns)
fig.show()
```